# Python Import Syntax Rules

Tags: python

I've been doing some searching but I couldn't find any consensus on the syntax allowed for imports.

I threw an syntax error for this import and was wondering if there was documentation on allowable syntax.

```
import some-module

# Do stuff.
```

Comment: could you add the full traceback to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use hyphen('-') symbol in any names in Python as this is regarded as substraction operator. Use underscore ('_') instead.